# Subtrair de um número os valores a sua direita em uma lista

Tags: javascript, c#, algoritmo

Tenho uma situação que é a seguinte:

dado um array com por exemplo 5 posições `[5, 10, 8, 2, 7]`
Preciso de um algorítimo que me permita fazer o seguinte:

1. Pegar o 5 e subtrair pelos números que estão depois da sua posição `[10, 8, 2, 7]`
2. Pegar o 10 e subtrair pelos números que estão depois da sua posição `[8, 2, 7]`
3. Pegar o 8 e subtrair pelos números que estão depois da sua posição `[2, 7]`

E assim por diante. Preciso armazenar o resultado destas subtrações em um novo array.

Pode ser em qualquer uma das duas linguagens.

Comment: Uma coisa a se notar é que isso não é diretamente possível usando uma pilha, a não ser que a linguagem/tecnologia não respeite os conceitos da estrutura. Se é um exercício da faculdade ou afins, vai ser necessário mover os elementos desta pilha pra outra estrutura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem mistério, é só fazer um laço pra passar por todos os elementos do array e dentro deste laço fazer outro laço que passe por todos os elementos **depois do atual** e fazer a subtração.

Não tem nada de pilha nisso, talvez o *array* que é recebido possa ser usado como uma pilha, mas aí a lógica seria ao contrário, ou seja, o primeiro elemento a ser usado seria o **7** e o **5** seria o último.

```js
var arr = [5, 10, 8, 2, 7];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var sub = arr[i];
  for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    sub -= arr[j];
  }
  
  console.log(arr[i], sub);
}
```

Em C#:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new [] { 5, 10, 8, 2, 7 };

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) 
        {
            var sub = arr[i];
            for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++) 
            {
                sub -= arr[j];
            }

            WriteLine($"Elemento: {arr[i]}  Subtração: {sub}");
        }
    }
}
```

[Você pode ver funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CCuVTo)

Comment: É isso mesmo que preciso. A variável sub que você acumula as subtrações eu vou substituir por um array que vai armazenando o resultado de cada operação ex: 5 - 10, 5 - 8, 5 - 2 e assim por diante.